# How do I find out monitor make / model?

Tags: drivers, monitor

My friend has recently bought a second-hand vehicle with an in-car computer and it's wired up to a touchscreen monitor on the dashboard (very impressive!).

Now, I've helped him install Ubuntu on it today but we can't establish the make and model of the connected touchscreen monitor to try and source the drivers to make the touchscreen function work.

Are there any Linux commands to work out the make / model of an attached monitor? I've tried Google which pointed me towards the `/etc/X11` directory but have had no joy with that.

Comment: Most likely, more info will be available after running `sudo lshw -sanitize` - please, edit the question and post output there

Comment: The options below seem to no longer work

Answer (score 8):

I can see the make and model of my monitor in  in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. However, it is output by the video driver, so I am not sure it is universal:

`[    26.795] (II) RADEON(0): Monitor name: DELL U2412M`

If that does not work, install [edid-decode](https://packages.ubuntu.com/edid-decode) and point it to `/sys/class/drm/*/edid` as its manual suggests:

```
ls /sys/class/drm/*/edid | xargs -n 1 edid-decode | grep Manufacturer:
```

Comment: This option came the closest how ever on my display it responded with dell model 4096 which ended up being useless.  The 2nd display which I didn't care about of course responded with a proper model number

Answer (score 4):

`lshw` or `sudo lshw` will work better than `lspci`.

Answer (score 4):

Was looking for the answer myself on Fedora.
This will give you a long list for all video related questions:

```
xrandr -q --verbose | less
```

Look for EDID string, and copy/paste it to a file e.g. monitor.txt (maybe there is a better way.)
Then use:

```
edid-decode monitor.txt
```

to get all the info about your monitor from EDID string.

If you have only one monitor you could do something like:

```
xrandr -q --verbose | grep -i EDID -A 8 | grep -v EDID | sed s/\\t//g | edid-decode
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work better (all others answers didn't work 100% here):

```
for file in `ls -1 /sys/class/drm/*/edid`; do text=$(tr -d '\0' <"$file"); if [ -n "$text" ]; then edid-decode "$file" | grep -e Manufacturer: -e Product; sleep 0.0001; fi done
```

I tested here with 2 monitors. My primary is a builtin laptop monitor and the secondary is a DELL 25". This was the output:

```
Manufacturer: DELL Model 53359 Serial Number 809781068
Display Product Serial Number: YKFWP5790DGL
Display Product Name: DELL U2515H
Manufacturer: LGD Model 1133 Serial Number 0
```

You must have installed the `edid-decode` in your distro. My setup is DELL Latitude e5450 with Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

Install the package `read-edid` and use the command:

```
sudo get-edid | parse-edid
```

In my system the relevant output is:

```
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
<some messages>
Section "Monitor"
   Identifier "S22B300"
   ModelName "S22B300"
   VendorName "SAM"
<other info>
```

"SAM" is the code for "Samsung", found in http://edid.tv/manufacturer/.

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
lspci
```

Your monitor should be listed there somewhere.

Comment: The monitor is not attachted to the PCI bus.

Answer (score 1):

Install HardInfo application and see info via GUI

[Look at screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYldX.png)
[image]